# Display my score when countdown has ended

Tags: jquery, html, css, setinterval, countdown

This is probably a very novice question but I have a game with a timer which gradually runs down, When it does run down I am displaying the score on a GAME OVER page.

As the displaying of the score is linked to the timer it keeps displaying the score every second. How would I stop it doing that?

```
var doUpdate = function() {
$('.countdown').each(function() {
  var count = parseInt($(this).html());
  if (count !== 0) {
    $(this).html(count - 1);
  } else {
    $('.gameover h4').append( "YOU SCORED "+score+"!!!" );
    $('.gameover').show();

  }
});
};

 // Schedule the update to happen once every second
 setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
```

Is there any way of making a listener that checks the count so I don't have to have the append function in the setInterval, or possibly have the else function destroy the setinterval timer

Thanks

Heres a demo (possibly) http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/wackamouse/index2.html

Comment: just an idea calling the above function on click of canvas/div rather then time interval.

Comment: How about using the .text() instead of .append()?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `clearInterval` like this.

```
var timeoutev ;
var doUpdate = function() {
$('.countdown').each(function() {
  var count = parseInt($(this).html());
  if (count !== 0) {
    $(this).html(count - 1);
  } else {
    $('.gameover h4').append( "YOU SCORED "+score+"!!!" );
    $('.gameover').show();
    clearInterval(timeoutev);
  }
});
};
 // Schedule the update to happen once every second
 timeoutev = setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
```